# Retrieve an Entity value to add to return parameter

Tags: asp.net, backend

I have this method:

```
 private List < ReportParameter > ParametrosReporte() {
      List < ReportParameter > Parametros = new List < ReportParameter > ();
      try {
        int ? int_Ejercicio = this.radcmbEjercicio.SelectedItem == null ? 0 : this.radcmbEjercicio.SelectedValue.ToInt();
        int ? int_Periodo = this.radcmbPeriodo.SelectedItem == null ? 0 : this.radcmbPeriodo.SelectedValue.ToInt();
        int ? int_BSC = this.radcmbBSC.SelectedItem == null ? 0 : this.radcmbBSC.SelectedValue.ToInt();

        Parametros.Add(Reportes.ParametrosReporte("pe_Ejercicio", int_Ejercicio.ToString()));
        Parametros.Add(Reportes.ParametrosReporte("pe_Mes", int_Periodo.ToString()));
        Parametros.Add(Reportes.ParametrosReporte("pe_BSC", int_BSC.ToString()));


        catBSC _catBSC = new catBSC() {
          mdUsuarioCaptura = new Entidades.Usuario() {
            UsuarioID = ((Usuario) Session["User"]).UsuarioID,
          }
        };
        Parametros.Add(Reportes.ParametrosReporte("pe_Usuario", UsuarioID ));

        return Parametros;
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Error en ParametrosReporte", ex);
      }
    }
```

As you can see I have  logic to retrieve user who is logged in as:

```
  catBSC _catBSC = new catBSC() {
              mdUsuarioCaptura = new Entidades.Usuario() {
                UsuarioID = ((Usuario) Session["User"]).UsuarioID,
              }
            };
```

but before retrieve it, I want to call it into Parametros.Add like:

```
Parametros.Add(Reportes.ParametrosReporte("pe_Usuario", UsuarioID ));
```

But I can´t because UsuarioID is out of scope and it throws me

> UsuarioID does not exist in the current context

How can I call it and attach to my `Parametros.Add`?

Comment: You could create a local variable outside of where that new CatBSC scope and in that scope, assign the UsuarioID to it.

Comment: I try it but it doesn´t work, sorrry I forget to comment it, or can you show your method to do it?, it´s possible I´m doing incorrect form @AnthonyVoelker

Comment: Did you try declaring the variable near where you declare the new list? I think one of the things that is complicating this is the use of the object initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a local variable above your creation of `catBSC` and then use that in both locations:

```
var usuarioID = ((Usuario) Session["User"]).UsuarioID

catBSC _catBSC = new catBSC() {
    mdUsuarioCaptura = new Entidades.Usuario() {
        UsuarioID = usuarioID
    }
};

Parametros.Add(Reportes.ParametrosReporte("pe_Usuario", usuarioID));
```

You can replace `var` with the actual type, but I didn't want to make an assumption about what this was in your scenario.

Comment: It should work but I found  more simple solution like: `var usuarioID = new Usuario() { UsuarioID = ((Usuario)Session["User"]).UsuarioID };`

Comment: That is something different. In that case `usuarioID` will be an instance of `Usuario` rather than whatever `UsuarioID` is.

Comment: both ends to same result, difference is I need to retrieve value like this:  `Parametros.Add(Reportes.ParametrosReporte("pe_Usuario", usuarioID.UsuarioID.ToString()))`

Comment: Yes, that's the difference I was talking about. In this case, you'd be better naming `usuarioID` as `usuario` because that's what it is. I hope that makes sense.